# Animating an Arc with Timeline

Tags: animation, javafx-2, javafx

In my smithchart project i am trying to animate an arc. I calculated start and stop angles via f which returns an double but could not find a way to use that angles. The point is angles which has double type can not be used in KeyValue which accepts WriteableValue.

```
double angle;
angle = f();
KeyValue keyAngle = new KayValue(angle, 360.0);
```

Also casting angle to WritableValue has no effect.
Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Animation API works with properties (which implement WritableValue). Thus if you want to change `startAngle` of your arc using animation you should provide `Arc#startAngleProperty()` to `KeyValue`:

```
    KeyValue kv = new KeyValue(arc.startAngleProperty(), my_double_angle_value);
```

An example of the animated arc:

```
    Arc arc = ArcBuilder.create()
            .centerX(150)
            .centerY(150)
            .radiusX(100)
            .radiusY(50)
            .startAngle(0)
            .length(30)
            .type(ArcType.ROUND)
            .fill(Color.RED)
            .build();

    Pane root = new Pane();
    root.getChildren().add(arc);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello Arc!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    KeyValue kv = new KeyValue(arc.startAngleProperty(), 360);
    KeyFrame kf = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(3), kv);

    Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
    timeline.setAutoReverse(false);
    timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.getKeyFrames().add(kf);
    timeline.play();
```